# In emacs, could not found bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs, rvm

My system is Mac OS X 10.10, I use **rvm** to manage rails, in emacs's shell, I run

```
bundle exec rake test
```

I got an error:

```
command not found: bundle
```

then I installed rvm.el, and enabled in .emacs, but the error is still exist!

What should I do?

Need your help! Thank you very much!

I found **$PATH** in iterm is different from emacs's shell's **$PATH**.

I tried to add **exec-path-from-shell** in my .emacs, but it's still not work!

> (when (memq window-system '(mac ns))
>   (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))

ps: in iterm's the $PATH is:

```
/Users/zwb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/zwb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/Users/zwb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/zwb/.rvm/bin
```

in emacs's shell the $PATH is:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/zwb/.rvm/bin
```

in emacs's eshell the $PATH is same as iterm.

Comment: I have no experience with emacs shell, but in the normal course of things, this error message would suggest that either you haven't installed bundler, or that its executable isn't in your PATH for some reason.

Comment: You are right! I found $PATH's value in iterm is different from emacs's shell's $PATH! How to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know, but I'm glad I could help. Perhaps you should update your question, since it appears that your issue is specifically with setting $PATH within emacs shell. I do know that RVM added some magic to my .bash_profile that makes it work - maybe that's a clue.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll update my question as you told.

Comment: This might be an emacs package that helps, I use it to set $PATH for eshell correctly: https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell

Comment: I find emacs's eshell's $PATH is right, but emacs's shell's $PATH is not correct! Also projectile-rails cann't work correct because of $PATH

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/tobiassvn/bundler.el/issues/3) is a solution that enabled me to run `M-x ! RET bundle exec rake test` in emacs. You must include the following to your `.emacs`:

```
(if (not (getenv "TERM_PROGRAM"))
(setenv "PATH"
        (shell-command-to-string "source $HOME/.zshrc && printf $PATH")))
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the RVM lib for Emacs solved all the headaches:

https://github.com/senny/rvm.el